# Visual studio can't find a controller even though I have added a reference to it and made sure it is public

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have a Unit Test solution that references the main solution for the controller.

Reference: `using Solution.Controllers;`

Unit Test class:

```
namespace solution.UnitTests.SolutionTests.ControllersTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class BrandCategoryControllerTests
    {
        private BrandCategoryController _brandCategoryController;
        [TestInitialize]
        public void Init()
        {
            _brandCategoryController = new BrandCategoryController();
        }
    }
}
```

The controller it is referencing is in Solution/Controllers folder.

The file begins with:

```
namespace Solution.Controllers
{
    public class BrandCategoryController : Controller
```

So I don't see why it can't find it. I've tried the intellisense and it doesn't recognize it. I've tried Cleaning and rebuilding the solution and closing and reopening visual studio. The annoying part is I have another controller and another controller test class both of which share the same folder structures and they work fine.

The error I am getting is `"The type or namespace "BrandCategoryController" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"` I have added a using Directive and have tried using the full reference on the private variable.

Comment: please recheck your namespaces: the controller is in ```LandOfBedsAdmin1.Controllers```, did you have that line in your test ```using LandOfBedsAdmin1.Controllers;``` ?

Comment: using Solutuib.Controllers; is in the test file. I've changed the references to LandOfBedsAdmin1 to Solution for the purpose of this question to just keep it simple.

Comment: Ok for clarification when you say can't find what do you mean. Do you get an exception? what? The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: @JackTyler here is a suggestion. depending on the version of your IDE you can click on the class in the test the type `Ctrl + .` that is control plus dot and see what the IDE suggests. If it is a namespace issue then it will show you what using you should be using. If it suggests you create the class then it definitely cannot find the class is thinks you are trying to create one.

Comment: I've used that and it asks if I want to generate the class. This what I mean when I say it can't find it. Normally there is a suggest for either a using statement or a direct reference but neither shows.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the assembly reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this working. The way it was fixed was I added a new controller to that folder to see if the intellisense would pick it up and when I did and checked the intellisense it picked up all three of the controllers in there. The original, the one I wanted and the new one. So I deleted the new one I created and it works fine now. Not Sure what caused this.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the `Solution.Controllers` project separately and fix build errors.